# Building 3D printer: LM8UU bearing can't fit into

Tags: diy-3d-printer, bearing

I'm new to 3D printing and I'm learning how to build my own 3D printer.

I bought polymer LM8UU bearings and I'm trying to fit onto a rod of dimension: D8 mm * L300 mm. Sadly it doesn't fit, I was wondering if I would need to buy new rod?

If so, what size of diameter should be used?  General guidelines I need to look out for are also appreciated?

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Please explain if the bearing does not fit *into* some cavity or *onto* a shaft, that makes a big difference. As it is asked now it looks like the 2 are not compatible. My comment got too big to fit, so I posted an answer that also addresses fitting into something, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bearing on a shaft

An 8 mm (ID, Internal Diameter) bearing should always fit on an 8 mm (OD, Outer Diameter) shaft. If it does not fit, one of the 2 is of a different size. Please use a caliper to determine the size of both.

#### Bearing in a housing

If it is the outer size of the bearing, i.e. fitting in a printed carriage or a bearing housing (e.g. SCxxUU), you should be aware of the different sizes of polymer bearings. E.g. there are RJMP-01-xx and RJ4JP-01-xx types of polymer bearings (xx denotes the shaft diameter, e.g. 08 for 8 mm shafts).

For RJMP-01-xx bearings (**not** compatible with LMxxUU bearings):

```
// Parameters for RJMP-01-xx (shaft size xx, all dimensions in [mm])
// Designation  d1  d2  B   B1      s   dn
//-------------------------------------------
// RJMP-01-08   8   16  25  16.2    1.1  15.2
```

For RJ4JP-01-xx bearings (compatible with LMxxUU bearings):

```
// Parameters for RJ4JP-01-xx (shaft size xx, all dimensions in [mm])
// Designation  d1  d2  B   B1      s   dn
//-------------------------------------------
// RJ4JP-01-08  8   15  24  17.5    1.1  14.3
```

*d1 is the inner diameter, d2 the outer diameter and B the length of the bearing*

The RJ4JP-01-08 bearings are drop-in replacements for the LM8UU linear bearings. Note that the RJMP-01-08 have a larger outer diameter and do not fit into the regular bearing housings. The increased thickness gives the bearings more rigidity.